# Clean Windows 10 upgrade while booting up from the DVD

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10

I want to upgrade to Windows 10 and cannot boot to the DVD in order to do a clean install.

While booting the DVD, it stops at the blue Windows logo over a black background (no spinner). The laptop is currently running Windows 7 Home Premium x64 SP1. The laptop is a Samsung RF710 (i5, 6GB RAM).

This is a last ditch attempt as I'm not going anywhere with the in-place upgrade.

Comment: How did you create the DVD? You might consider re-downloading and creating.

Comment: I used the Media Creation Tool on another PC.

Comment: Upgrade from 7 to 10 is easier to do it while booted into W7, you can choose Not to keep anything during upgrade which is the same as a clean install.

Comment: @Moab I'm stuck there too (essentially, I get a popup with the following message: "Windows 10 Installation Failed." I've searched quite a bit about this for the past few days without success. I was hoping this approach would yield better results.

Comment: W10 creates logs when it fails to install>>>>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/928901/log-files-that-are-created-when-you-upgrade-to-a-new-version-of-window

Comment: @Moab Yep. I've been looking at these, but it's not readily apparent what the issue is. Some googling brings up articles/posts. After having tried some of the fixes, I'm still stuck. I was hoping this approach could get me further.

Comment: Strangely enough, swapped to a USB drive and was able to get further. @harrymc was on to something. After googling a bunch of errors, one of them popped a few results that were helpful indicate a media or drive issue. Much quicker with the USB drive too.

Comment: If you were to share the errors we may be able to help more.

Comment: @music2myear I could create a new post I suppose. However, I suspect the hardware doesn't support Windows 10. It's a 2010 laptop. Even Samsung can't give me a clear answer to confirm that it's supported or not.

Comment: Why do you need a new post? There's a perfectly functional Edit button and we encourage people to edit their questions to improve them, add information, and make them more answerable.